# What are Some Energy Boosters

Tags: energy-drinks

First of all, I am not new to the world of fitness and bodybuilding. I have been training for 4 years straight. I've missed days here and there, but never been away for more than 3-4 days. I can lift a lot and I've always done it.

However, I have recently started to lose a significant amount of my energy half way through my workout (after an hour of working out since I usually work out for 2 hours 5-6 days a week).

At this point you can assume I have NEVER had any energy drinks in my whole life. I honestly am not aware of what they are and how they accomplish their task, and I don't take anything I don't know.

What I am trying to find out is:

1. what should I consider doing (whether using energy boosters or anything else)?
2. What are the side effects of those energy drinks advertised here and there?
3. Should I consider taking any?

I don't know if my age matters, but in case it does, I am 24 years old.

Comment: When do you take your rest days? How much of your routine is strength training and how much metabolic conditioning? Also, have you had changes to your sleep routine, diet, stress levels, or any other major changes in your life that might be affecting your energy that you're aware of?

Comment: My rest day is almost always Sunday. About 80% of my workout focuses on strength. I haven't been having a lack of sleep recently, but I do go to sleep late sometimes. I still get a minimum of 8 hours of sleep though. And yes I am a bit stressed over a few things in my life

Comment: See Tracy's answer, and pay particular attention to the last two sentences. If you are suddenly losing energy 1/2 way through a workout, *something* has changed. Energy drinks are a mask, and of dubious value at the best of times. Figure out what's changed, first.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things here that are worth looking at further.

Firstly, obviously, you are very keen on working out.  I am pleased to see that you are having a day off a week.

However, if you have been working out day in, day out over a long period, it maybe that you need a few days off.  Any decent training program will have hard easy weeks, and even hard easy months.

Have you heard of periodisation?(regarding training plans)
You may find this interesting http://www.muscleandstrength.com/articles/designing-training-routines-using-periodization.html

So I would start with having 2-3 days off.

Next I would look at your diet - you say you have stress in your life at the moment.  Is it causing you not to eat so well?

Remember food is fuel - 2 hours is a longtime to workout if you are not eating properly.

If after a few days off, and checking your diet, things still haven't improved, I would consider a trip to the doctor for a blood test.  It could simply be that you are low in iron.  (you didn't mention if you eat red meat?).

As to the energy drinks, I personally would not suggest you go down this route.  You need to find the cause of your problem, and not mask the problems.

Answer (score 4):

Fadi Hanna AL-Kass, 
 
You said you've been training for 4 years straight. Have you been performing the same routine or mixing them up? *Many times, people get bored after performing the same routines for a very long time.* So, if you notice that you've been performing the same routine for a while, that could be the reason for your lackluster energy. Go online, obtain new exercises, and incorporate them into your routines. That might renew your energy and enthusiasm.
 
 Second, *do you train because you love doing it* or *has it become a chore?* If you feel that it's becoming a duty, it's time to take a break for a few days. Go have fun with something else. Let your body relax and crave the training. When you come back, your body'll just lap it up :). 
 
 Third, you mentioned *(in the comments)* that you're stressed in a few areas of your life. Have you noticed this low energy in other areas of your life? If you have, your stressful state of mind could also be the reason for this low energy. Again, the solution is to take some time off to resolve these issues. 
 
To answer your questions, ***you should not consider taking energy boosters.* These drinks have too much sugar or chemicals with adverse effects on the body.** Rather, you should improve your nutrition and *take supplements.* While there are many supplements in the market, take multi-vitamins that are rich in

- Vitamin B complex (B1, B2, B3, B5, B6, B9, B12, Biotin)
- Iron
- Magnesium
- Zinc

You should also consume food that contain these vitamins; they include spinach, watermelon, broccoli, milk, potatoes, bananas, lean meats, lentils, etc. 
 
Eat right, take time off, and enjoy life :).